# Internet Explorer 11 CSS dropdown menu issue

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-11

I am having an issue with my dropdown menu in Internet Explorer 11.
There are blue lines at the top and bottom. I believe they correspond to the background color. 
This is what it looks like
[image: DropDown]

Here is the css that corresponds to it..

```
dropdown-menu {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

I am guessing it has to do with the height being off in the box, but I am unsure how I would correct that. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Looking through the css on the page my original thought of the code that was generating the dropdown menu was wrong. It's actually this.

```
.selection-cell {
    width: 30.2969px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url('images/buttons/control.png') no-repeat;
    background-color: #3498db!important;
    background-position: 8px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: 13px 13px;
    margin-bottom: inherit;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.selection-cell:hover{
    background: url('images/buttons/control-selected.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 8px 8px;
    background-size: 13px 13px;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
.selection-cell option{
    background: white;
    /*border-left: 1px solid black;*/
    -moz-clear: both;
    -ms-clear: both;
    clear: both;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide HTML and other CSS? Have you checked the padding?

Comment: Yes we need to see the whole code because it seems that there are margins, paddings, heights etc cascading from other elements into this dropdown menu.

Comment: After messing around with IE 11's developer tools I manages to find this.
My guess at the original style it was using was wrong. It's actually this.
http://i.imgur.com/4rmTWfA.png?1